# How do I use javascript to filter the right date out of a data file?

Tags: javascript

first question here. I searched if I find the same question somewhere else but I couldn't so here we go. Excuse me for mediocre english skills hope you get what I am asking for.

I just started working on Javascript & got a Data.Js that contains data that has to be Implemented the project.

Currently, the date is Displayed this way 
: "from": "2018-04-14T08:30:00+02:00", "

There is more kinds of data inside that I refer to by using var elements={}

I gave those elements classes in my Index.html & am able to transfer those datas onto the page using

```
"const entries = data.container.entries.entry;
    console.log(entries); 
    for (var i in entries) {
        console.log("ausgabe",i); 
        elements.heads[i].innerHTML = entries[i].to; "
```

So back to my question, I also added a a function that is ment to give me the specific day out of the day, since this & the time is all that I currently need so basically this

```
 "original :  "to": "2018-04-15T08:30:00+02:00",
```

"What I need:  "to": "The day of the week, The exact time(hours, minutes) displayed like"until Monday,8.30  ",

The code that I found online to get the day (I changed the names of the eek to german, the way they are ment to be displayed aswell.

```
  function myFunction() {

     var d = new Date();

    var weekday = new Array(7);

    weekday[0] = "Sonntag";

    weekday[1] = "Montag";

    weekday[2] = "Dienstag";

    weekday[3] = "Mittwoch";

     weekday[4] = "Donnerstag";

     weekday[5] = "Freitag";

     weekday[6] = "Samstag";

     console.log

     var n = weekday[d.getDay()];

     document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = n;
```

So to sum it up, how do I connect those functions to the array to make it filter out the date & the time? thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) function to parse your date string into a `Date` object into a Long Date format and then use [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to get it translated according to your locale

**EDIT:** As I said before, you have to combine both functions. Probably your best bet is to use a built-in function like `toLocaleDateString()` instead of reinventing the wheel. But to do so you need to convert your string to a `Date()` object because `toLocaleString` works with `Date` objects. So, in short, I prepared a little snippet that attempts to solve your problem.

```js
function parsedata() {
  // read your data from input
  var originDate = document.getElementById("inputDate").value;
  // create a Date object
  var dateObject = new Date(originDate)
  // create options object for date parsing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString for more options 
  var dateOptions = {
    weekday: 'long',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };
  // create string with parsed date
  var locale = dateObject.toLocaleString("de-DE", dateOptions)
  //assigns the value inside <p> for testing purposes
  document.getElementById("parsed").innerText = locale
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="parser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Date to parse: </p><input id="inputDate" value="2018-04-14T08:30:00+02:00"><button onclick="parsedata()">try!</button>
  <p>Parsed date: </p>
  <p id="parsed"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

In short, what it does is the following:

- Reads your date (YMMV, change this to adapt the code to read from external file or user input. **Also, be sure to perform validation**
- Creates a `Date` object
- Creates an object containing options required to your desired output. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to get more options
- creates a string with these options applied
- outputs the string to a `<p>` element for debugging purposes.

Comment: I'll google for instructions on how to do that since i never used Parse but I think this will help a lot thanks!

Comment: If I have time later, I will elaborate a bit more this answer, but this should put you in the path of the answer you are looking for

Comment: Please look at my full answer @Qaush

Comment: If you find a particular answer useful, please mark it as accepted as a courtesy to the user who answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly (I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, i.e. what you want to do with the formatted weekday), here is a way to do it, largely based on your code.

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
var entries = data.container.entries.entry;

weekday[0] = "Sonntag";
weekday[1] = "Montag";
weekday[2] = "Dienstag";
weekday[3] = "Mittwoch";
weekday[4] = "Donnerstag";
weekday[5] = "Freitag";
weekday[6] = "Samstag";

function getFormattedWeekday(d) {
    var formattedWeekday = weekday[d.getDay()];
    return formattedWeekday;
}

for (var i in entries) {
    weekday = getFormattedWeekday(i);
    elements.heads[i].innerHTML = weekday;
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your question! I want the weekday and the hour to be displayed in a specific place in the page im working on. I will try your solution and once i get the day working i am pretty sure i will get the hour working too!

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: d.getDay is not a function
    at getFormattedWeekday

Comment: and of course I ment thanks for your answer, not question haha

Comment: Hey man! I worked on the code and got it to work thanks a lot this answered my question perfectly, just need to add the time onto it now too. :D